# MySQL Group Replication starts master node with super_read_only

Tags: mysql, docker, configuration, replication, master-slave

I am trying to set up MySQL group replication. Only problem is, that when I try to start replication group, It starts with super_read_only.

Here the configurations in `my.cnf` file

```
[mysqld]

max_binlog_size = 4096
default_authentication_plugin     = mysql_native_password

log_bin                           = mysql-bin-1.log
enforce_gtid_consistency          = ON
gtid_mode                         = ON
log_slave_updates                 = ON
binlog_checksum                   = NONE

plugin-load-add                   = group_replication.so
plugin-load-add                   = mysql_clone.so
relay_log_recovery                = ON
transaction_write_set_extraction  = XXHASH64
loose_group_replication_start_on_boot                    = OFF
loose_group_replication_group_name                       = 74fe8890-679f-4e93-9169-a7edfbc1d427
loose_group_replication_group_seeds                      = mysql_cluster_mysql0_1:3306, mysql_cluster_mysql1_1:3306, mysql_cluster_mysql2_1:3306
loose_group_replication_single_primary_mode              = ON
loose_group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = OFF
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

instances are run inside docker, that's why group seed addresses has these hostnames.

Also here the procedure for running master instance.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `set_as_master`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `set_as_master`()
BEGIN
  SET @@GLOBAL.group_replication_bootstrap_group=1;
  CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'repl'@'%';
  GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO repl@'%';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_USER='root' FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';
  START GROUP_REPLICATION;
  -- SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

After running `CALL start_as_master;` in Sqlyog, process stucks on below lines.

```
'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.

2021-03-03T21:47:55.934818Z 8 [System] [MY-013587] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Plugin 'group_replication' is starting.'

2021-03-03T21:47:55.935929Z 9 [System] [MY-011565] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Setting super_read_only=ON.'
```

Why does it run with `super_read_only=ON`?
Is there anything I miss during configuration or running script?

MySQL version is 8.0.23.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this then restart the replication

set global super_read_only=0;

Let me know if it works